# Does Brain Damage Lead to changes in Subconscious Thoughts?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality

We all know that brain damage can alter personality. The common example is Phineas Gage. I tried researching the effects of brain damage on subconscious thought processing on Google, but I couldn't find anything directly related. Is there significant research on the effects of subconscious thoughts and brain damage? Brain damage can make us process information slowly and can alter our thinking (again Phineas Gage), **but do we know if brain damage affects the subconscious**? These questions arose when I found this somewhat unrelated article (https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02207-1) on visual form agnosia. Patients have a hard time saying the orientation of a pencil but can perfectly grab it. It appears to me that even though parts of the brain were impaired, something deeper was not.